# Cannot display the star in the rating system in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, rating-system

I have searched how to create the rating system already and I have tried to use two ways to do it. But it still cannot function properly. It only displays the radio button without any star icons are being displayed. The browsers I use are Firefox and Chrome. What is wrong with my code, as I have include all js, css files in the same directory as the jsp? Is it the javascript doesn't embedded properly? 
I find the demo and downloads in this page:
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

The below is my code:

```
    <title>Star rating demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.rating.css">
    <link href='jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.MetaData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.rating.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" class="star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" class="star">
    </form>
</body>
```

And I have tried another example from this link as well http://rog.ie/blog/css-star-rater
But again it can just display the grey star and cannot function properly. Is there anything I have done it wrong.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: Yes... I just find this there are four errors for example SyntaxError: illegal character jquery.js:1:0, when I click the script name it highlights the first row... So what happens? is it cannot use this /*!

Comment: Sorry I find some errors like SyntaxError: illegal character jquery.js:1:0, I am not so good at debugging js using this kind of tool, can i know which row got such error? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your javascript and css too, also not sure you need all those jquery libraries. Just importing jQuery should take care of it

Comment: But i have included in this way, is there anything wrong? <link href='jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: If this jsp is in the same folder as the js and css files it's ok, but I'd doubt it.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory in the same folder, I unzipped the package in the same folder... But, I don't know why it seems the js doesn't work properly.

Comment: And I just find that it works in IE, but not work in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but the website says it supports all of these.....

Comment: Sorry I find some errors like SyntaxError: illegal character jquery.js:1:0, I am not so good at debugging js using this kind of tool, can i know which row got such error? Many thanks!